# Issues while setting up wordpress on a virtual host in ubuntu@ec2

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Trying to setup Wordpress on one of the virtual hosts on my ubuntu ec2 instance. Facing two issues.

1. `mydomain.com` is redirecting to `mydomain.com/wordpress`, when I
   wanted Wordpress to be rendered on `mydomain.com`.
2. The themes are not displaying correctly, whether in
   `mydomain.com/wordpress` or while installing in `wp-admin`. I can see the themes are present in `/var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/themes`.

Browser console shows following:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/genericons/genericons.css/?ver=3.4.1".
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css/?ver=4.4.2".
?ver=20160816:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
?ver=20160816:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Context:

1) Installed Wordpress by following: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WordPress.

2) Files in /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/:

```
index.php:
    <?php
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );

.htaccess:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

wordpress/ -> /usr/share/wordpress
```

3) Content of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html

<Directory "/var/www/mydomain.com/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Alias /wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content

<Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

4) Content of /etc/wordpress/config-mydomain.com.php:

```
<?php
# Created by /usr/share/doc/wordpress/examples/setup-mysql 
#...mysql entries...
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/lib/wordpress/wp-content');
?>
```

5) Entries in mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php:

```
Wordpress address: mydomain.com/wordpress
Site address: mydomain.com
```